# Как решить ошибку EREFUSED с монго дб?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodemon

Делаю проект на ноде жс, иногда от базы данных много дб прилетает ошибка, причем иногда пропадает иногда появляется.
Айпи прописаны
Вот текст ошибки

```
Error: querySrv EREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vwwe7.mongodb.net
at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:202:19) {
errno: 'EREFUSED',
code: 'EREFUSED',
syscall: 'querySrv',
hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vwwe7.mongodb.net'
}
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Comment: прям [ничегошеньки](https://www.google.com/search?q=mongo+cluster+EREFUSED+dns.js) не нашли?

Comment: Нашел, но говорю это не работает

Comment: добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос какие решения вы пробовали

Comment: убирать +src обавил в разрешение все ip адреса

Comment: в списке по моей ссылке есть два решения, выглядящих потенциально применимыми к вашему случаю: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57749029/4496422 и https://stackoverflow.com/a/55947278/4496422

Comment: я добавил поменял на другую версию но теперь оно будет вечно конектится, тоесть высчечиваться start on 3000 не будет

Comment: тогда второй ответ. его можно и через настройки ОС и через https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/dns.html#dns_dns_setservers_servers